# How to use DLookup criteria from different tables in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am very new to VBA and Access, and have been madly searching the internet for answers, but I seem to be stuck on this one. I may be getting stuck thinking in Excel spreadsheet logic when trying to design this in Access.

I have two tables, REQUESTFORM and CLIENTDATABASE. The Request form has various fields generated from incoming emails. My intent is for the ClientDatabase to auto-populate new CLIENTID's when emails from new individuals arrive in the RequestForm table, and add the appropriate CLIENTID to the REQUESTFORM table. The REQUESTFORM has fields for NEWFIRSTNAME and NEWLASTNAME, while CLIENTDATABASE will have fields FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME, to keep the field names different. I want CLIENTDATABASE to have the primary key data, so I can handle any spelling mistakes that come in.

Using DLOOKUP is similar to excel's VLOOKUP, but DLOOKUP only seems to use criteria in the same table. In Excel you could 'point' to other tables if necessary.

So when I try this in a query:

```
NameMatch: DLookUp("[ClientID]","ClientDatabase","[FirstName]=[NewFirstName] And [LastName]=[NewLastName]")
```

It doesn't seem to be working because it doesn't recognize NewFirstName, because it isn't in the ClientDatabase, it is in RequestForm.

I have tried coding a user defined function in VB, but I keep running into the same problem, even if I reduce it to one criteria. I can work with one criteria if I have to by combining first and last name as a fullname field, but still.

```
Public Function NameMatch(ByVal pInput As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next

    NameMatch = DLookup("[ClientID]", "ClientDatabase", "[FirstName] = 'pInput'")
End Function
```

Is there a way to code the user defined function to define 'pInput' as [NewFirstName] and successfully see it? Or write the formula better in the query? I don't get an error with the UDF, just a blank. There's probably a dozen other pitfalls I've missed as well. Any help appreciated.

Stardance

Comment: This is very possible... but where are you using it, In a form, In a query etc.?

Comment: NameMatch = nz(DLookup("[ClientID]", "ClientDatabase", "[FirstName] = 'pInput'"),DLookup("[ClientID]", "RequestForm", "[FirstName] = 'pInput'"))

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this where you concate the values into the search criteria:

```
NameMatch: DLookUp("[ClientID]","ClientDatabase","[FirstName] = '" & [NewFirstName] & "' And [LastName] = '" & [NewLastName] & "'")
```